# How do I compile web workers with vue3+vite?

Tags: vuejs3, web-worker, vite

I have a simple Web Worker which executes a initiates and handles messages from a websocket. The logic for the handler is imported from another module "MessageHandler". The reason for this is that the websockets rely on an external dependency (stompjs) anyway, and I would like to keep a single module with the message hangling logic for browsers which don't support webworkers.

```js
import { connect, destroy } from "../src/utilities/MessageHandler";

onmessage = (message) => {
  const {type, value} = message.data;
  switch (type?.toLowerCase()) {
    case "connect":
      connect(value, message => postMessage(message))
      break;
    case "destroy":
      destroy();
      break;
  }
}
```

On the Dev server, this works fine, and I can place the file in the public folder, and start the Worker with:

```js
  if (typeof Worker !== "undefined") {
    const workerUrl = new URL("/worker.js", import.meta.url);
    const worker = new Worker(workerUrl, {type:"module"});
    console.log(workerUrl);
    worker.postMessage({type:"connect", value: {...channelInfo}},);
    worker.onmessage = combineValues;
    onUnmounted(() => {
      worker.postMessage({type:"destroy"},);
      worker.terminate();
    })
  } else {
    console.log("Workers not allowed. Reverting to single threaded application.");
    connect(channelInfo, combineValues)
    onUnmounted(() => destroy())
  }
```

However when I build for production, the import from MessageHandler is not compiled into the worker file, and the program fails to execute. Is there a way to configure vite to bundle this web worker properly without having to manually copy all of the dependencies into the file, and does the WW file have to remain in the public folder? Bonus points if there is a way to do it using typescript for the Worker file instead of being forced back to JS.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The way to do this is to import the worker like this

```js
new Worker(
  new URL('./worker', import.meta.url),
  {type: 'module'}
);
```

where `./worker` is not in the public folder but in the src folder like any other import.

See [this section](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#web-workers) in the vite docs

Comment: I found in some cases, has to have the file extension added to it e.g. new URL('./file.js, import.meta.url) or else it would give weird MIME type errors

Comment: Testing this in Vite 5.1.4, this works but only if your web worker is JS, not TS.

Answer (score 14):

While the accepted answer is working well, vite provides an easier way to import workers using query suffix `?worker`.

Example:

```
import MyWorker from './worker?worker'

const worker = new MyWorker()
```

This is more useful for a number of reasons:

- You don't need to put your worker script in `public` folder. Instead you can include it in `src` folder.
- You can use aliases. For example if have `@` pointing to `src` folder, so you  do `import MyWorker from '@/worker?worker'`.
- If you use typescript in your vue project, you can use a typescript worker as well without the need to compile it separately.

More info: https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#web-workers

Comment: Trying this in Vite 5.1.4, it appears this works only if your web worker is JS, not TS. Might be a bug in Vite.