# Web worker file '404 not found' after Vite/Vue3 build

Tags: typescript, vue.js, web-worker, vite, pinia

I am trying to test using web workers in a Vite app, and when I run `npm run dev` it works as intended, but when I use `npm run build` and then use [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) in the `dist` folder, I get the error: `"GET /workers/test.worker.ts" Error (404): "Not found"`

My Vite app is the generic starter template with these sole additions:

### *@/stores/counter.ts*

```js
/* ... Inside Default Pinia Store ... */
function webworkerTest() {
    console.log("this is a test message, wahoo!!");
    const workerPath = "../workers/test.worker.ts";

    const worker = new Worker(new URL(workerPath, import.meta.url), {
      type: "module",
    }); 
// Note the same setup as the Vite docs, although without {type: "module"} the console
// throws "404 (Not Found)" -from build- or "Unexpected token 'export'" -from dev-

    console.log(workerPath, worker);
    worker.addEventListener("message", (message) => {
      console.log(message);
    });
    worker.postMessage("this is a test message to the worker");
  }
/* ... Insert webworkerTest into Default Pinia Store return statement ... */
```

### *@/workers/test.worker.ts*

```js
console.log("hello from a webworker");

addEventListener("message", (message) => {
  console.log("in webworker", message);
  postMessage("this is the response " + message.data);
});

// To avoid --isolatedModules error
export {};
```

### *@/components/HelloWorld.vue*

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useCounterStore } from "@/stores/counter";
const counterStore = useCounterStore();
counterStore.webworkerTest(); // Activate the test worker

defineProps<{
  msg: string;
}>();
</script>
```

#### Vite Options:

- Vue 3
- TypeScript
- Pinia
- ESLint
- Prettier

#### Sources:

- [Vite Docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#web-workers)
- [MDN Web Worker Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)
- [TypeScript Web Worker Example](https://github.com/zlepper/typescript-webworker)
- [How do I compile web workers with vue3+vite? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73862386/how-do-i-compile-web-workers-with-vue3vite)

#### Notes:

- I am fairly new to TypeScript and its various config options, although I have experience with C++ and JS
- I am using Composition API both in the Pinia store and the Vue SFCs
- I have even played around with the location of the `test.worker.ts` file, without any progress

### Update:

I have experimented with the other option, [Import with Query Suffixes](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#import-with-query-suffixes), and it works in both `dev` and `build`, but I don't know how or why it works and I'm not sure what to search for in order to learn more, so I made a [separate post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74270384/what-are-the-query-suffixes-referred-to-in-the-vite-docs) to try and get some insight.