# What are the "Query Suffixes" referred to in the Vite Docs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, web-worker, vite

I have been reading through the [Vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#import-with-query-suffixes) for Web workers, and it mentioned importing a file using "Query Suffixes," which I have never encountered and am not sure what to search for to learn more. I'm not sure if this is native to Node.js, Vite.js, or if it is a plugin that is built into Vite.

This is the specific section that I am referring to:

---

### Import with Query Suffixes

A web worker script can be directly imported by appending ?worker or ?sharedworker to the import request. The default export will be a custom worker constructor:

```js
import MyWorker from './worker?worker'

const worker = new MyWorker()
```

The worker script can also use import statements instead of importScripts() - note during dev this relies on browser native support and currently only works in Chrome, but for the production build it is compiled away.

By default, the worker script will be emitted as a separate chunk in the production build. If you wish to inline the worker as base64 strings, add the inline query:

```js
import MyWorker from './worker?worker&inline'
```

If you wish to retrieve the worker as a URL, add the url query:

```js
import MyWorker from './worker?worker&url'
```

See Worker Options for details on configuring the bundling of all workers.

---

### Update:

I found an [MDN page on `import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) that seems like a step in the direction that I am looking for, as well as [this MDN page on `import.meta`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import.meta) that looks a lot like what I am searching for. I tried following that lead, but it didn't help me understand this Vite feature any better.

Is the `?worker` query suffix a custom Vite implementation of `import.meta`?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't know it was Vite specific problem. But, this fixed my error.

```
import MyWorker from './worker?worker'

const worker = new MyWorker()
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! Fortunately, I was not receiving an error per se. Rather, I was trying to understand how the query suffixes work in order to better use them, but couldn't find any relevant documentation. As such, I'm not going to mark your response as the answer, but I do appreciate you taking the time to respond.